# Building your own gesture recognizer from touches methods?

Tags: ios, uikit, sprite-kit

I'm having an issue with swipe gesture recognizer - it is sometimes slow and requires some distance to detect. For example sometime when you move your finger just a little it won't detect.

I'm making a twitch game and handle my input with gestures in all four directions and this behavior leads to all sorts of confusion and irritates players.

So I figured I need to implement my own swipe recognizer. Or maybe there is a library done by someone else?

My thinking so far is to store a location of touch in `touchesBegan:` method and then check for new locations in `touchesMoved:` or `touchesEnded:` methods. Then I will compare the distance and direction and fire correct methods.

Is this a correct way to do this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a correct way but far from easy actually. I created a class that does something like that for me (for throwing a view actually).

What I do in this class is generate a point buffer and a date-time buffer which I can then use to compute things like speed, gesture length... On the outside it looks like this:

```
@property NSInteger maximumBufferSize;
@property (readonly) CGFloat traceLength;
@property (readonly) CGPoint traceSpeed;
- (void)begin:(CGPoint)point;
- (void)push:(CGPoint)point;
- (void)end:(CGPoint)point;
```

Pretty convenient to use. In your case `begin`, `push` and `end` are touches began, touches moved and touches ended (or canceled). Maximum buffer size is the number of points it will store (N last points received by touches that is).

You must understand you will probably need a bit more then that if you want to ignore none swipe gestures (user draws a circle with his finger for instance). To do such things you might want to compute an average way of the trace and then compare each sub-trace (`point[i+1] - point[i]`) so that `dot(trace.averageWay, sub-trace.averageWay) = 1+-trashold`.

Edit: added source link

[Source link](https://github.com/maticoblak/iOS-tools/tree/master/Classes/CGTools)

Comment: Thanks for input, is your class available anywhere to check out?

Comment: I added the swipeDirection getter on the class which effectively detects a swipe gesture in any direction and returns the way of the gesture or (0,0) if not a swipe gesture.

Answer (score 1):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

// Setting the swipe direction.
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

// Adding the swipe gesture on image view
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

}
if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but as I said I have this working at the moment and it fails to detect short swipes. That's why I'm thinking of rolling my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this tutorial 
[[http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites]](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites%5d)

I make sure that you will find the solutions for your problems.